# Cross-site scripting - Cookie encryption

Tags: java, cookies, xss, pattern-matching, security

I am developing a client-side proxy to counter Cross-site scripting attacks. All the requests from the browser will go through the proxy. I am able to classify the requests as local or cross-domain, using the Referer header and other things. But, I need to reduce the number of false positives.

For this, I will track the cookie sent from the web-server in a response and I will look for parts of this cookie in any cross-domain request, i.e., I will check for only the cross-site requests that carry sensitive information (cookie).

But this simple idea simply fails if the attacker constructs a HTTP response where cookie is encrypted and leaked.

For example,

cookie :

```
user=rahim;pass=asdf
```

The hacker constructs a request

```
www.evil.com?name=mihar&pass=fdsa
```

The attacker has simply reversed the cookie parameters. There are such innumerable number of ways the attacker can play with the cookie and fool the process.

I need an algorithm which checks just that. The cookie parameters should not be allowed to pass through in whatever form.

Answer (score 1):

your task is hopeless.  There is no way to tell what the true meaning of a cookie is.